# Download yesterdays file from FTP server

Tags: wget

How am I able to download files from a FTP server that have only been added yesterday? For all subfolders + keep the same structure.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a straight forward way to do this without scripting. Wget does not have a built in command to filter by date. Curl has -z:

```
curl -z "Oct 01 2015" "file"
```

But curl doesn't support wildcards for ftp / lacks wget's -r switch to recursively download an entire dir. With wget you can use --timestamping to only download new/changed files but that's for when you have a local mirror to compare against.

You're probably best off mounting the server with something like curlftpfs and then just using find and cp. I'm sure there's a neat way to script it with just wget but I'll leave that to someone more knowledgeable.

Comment: How can I do it with a script? I want to set a cronjob to download every days previous data

Comment: If you're doing it every day you can just do `wget --mirror` once and then cron `wget --timestamped` every night and it'll update your local archive with the new data.

Comment: See [section 5](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Time_002dStamping) of the wget manual for details. Probably the most straightforward way to go, just mirror and then do any kind of other processing (like if you want to sort the files in different folders per date or whatever) locally in the same cronjob.